# Customized item divider weirdness

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

http://codepen.io/pondnetic/pen/MwEqJK

Shouldn't these two things evaluate to be the same when $scope.theme is 'dark'?

```
<ion-item class="item-divider-dark">dark divider 1</ion-item>

<ion-item class="item-divider-{{theme}}">dark divider 2</ion-item>
```

The first dark divider looks right in my project using scss, but wrong in the codepen. The second dark divider looks exactly the same in my project and codepen, that is, completely wrong. Why is there a difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) in second variant

> The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.

```
<ion-item ng-class="item-divider-{{theme}}">dark divider 2</ion-item>
```

If you don't use `ng-class` the class name will not be parsed.

**EDIT**

Use `important` on `background-color` of `.item-divider-dark`:

```
background-color: #535353 !important;
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvZmdK)

Comment: close but not quite. <ion-item ng-class="'item-divider-' + theme">dark divider 2</ion-item> is what I needed. Thanks!!